# How to determine authentication requirements given 401 response?

Tags: java, http, url, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

I'm using the following code on the client side to take response of a protected website, which works pretty fine whenever there is no authentication request from server side:

```java
    final String targetURL   = "http://************";
    final String username    = "********";
    final String password    = "******";
    final int connectTimeout = 30000;
    
    final String username_password         = username + ":" + password;
    final byte[] usernamepassword          = (byte[])username_password.getBytes();
    final String encoded_username_password = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(usernamepassword);
    
    final URL url = new URL(targetURL);
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    
    connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded_username_password);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
      
    // response headers
    final Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
    
    for (final Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headerFields.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

However, when I try to connect with a specific (protected) webserver, the connection is refused with the **401** http status code.

> Key: null, Value: [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
> Key: WWW-Authenticate, Value: [Digest realm="Login to ********", qop="auth", nonce="*******", opaque=""]
> Key: Connection, Value: [close] Key: Content-Length, Value: [0]

Is it possible to infer from the above logged response what I'm missing ?

I mean, the snippet above is a well known Java [basic-authentication](/questions/tagged/basic-authentication) template, there are many examples everywhere with the same structure, so the issue seems likely related to the parameters issued as argument of the *[setRequestProperty()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.net.HttpURLConnection&method=setRequestProperty)* method.

This is what I took on request header by using ***Mozilla >> Web Developer >> Debug*** (where some fields are hidden by me):

> **Host**: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> **User-Agent**: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
>
> **Accept**: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> **Accept-Language**: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>
> **Accept-Encoding**: gzip, deflate
>
> **Connection**: keep-alive
>
> **Upgrade-Insecure-Requests**: 1
>
> **Pragma**: no-cache
>
> **Cache-Control**: no-cache
>
> **Authorization**: Digest username="", realm="Login to xxxxxxx", nonce="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx", uri="xxxxxxx", response="xxxxx", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="b2b43c8d9631354d"

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear on this point, I'm on the client side, so it is not a matter of filtering requests, I'm the one who is issuing requests to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question. My guess is you would like to filter the request based on the parameters and url so you can chhose to either serve content or reject and return 401.

In this case your question should be: How to filter which http requests requires authentication.

Depending on what framework your are using, in spring-boot, there is something called WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. It basically helps you with your problem. You can filter all the requests coming to your server.

Comment: I'm working at the client side, not at the webserver side; I did not mention before since I presumed it was clear, sorry. So, the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

It Simply because you are not authenticated to their server,

you need the use that protected server authentication, if you want to enable yourself to access their resource,

maybe u can check their website, or docs to get some some api key or 
some token (basic, bearer or whatever token)

then follow their guideline where to put that authentication in your request (usually if token will be in request payload, if api key or basic auth  will be in request header)

hope this helps

Comment: Actually, I am authenticated to the website; when I fill the pop-up authentication window with the above login/password at any web browser the credentials are accepted; For some reason authentication is not achieved programatically with the above code.

Comment: authenticated to the website doesnt mean you authenticated to that resource,

please also be more clearer with your question, it quite confusing to understand ur case

Comment: I'm prompted to give all information necessary, however you did not specify the point you did not understand; I gave the code of the client which make the request, and I also showed the response took  from the server; What else is needed to clarify?